# PostGIS query to get the closest data available

Tags: postgis, postgresql, knn, closest-distance

I've got three tables in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database:

1. referencia.comarcas_agrarias_centroides (holds geom centroids of agricultural regions)
2. referencia.estaciones_r_pen (holds geom locations of meteorological stations)
3. tesis.datos_meteo (holds meteorological data for each month, year and station)

What I need to perform is a query returning temperature and precipitation of April, May and June, for each region and year, **from the closest meteo station where data are available for that year** (not all stations have data for every year). Meaning that, if no data is available from the closest station, it should search for the next closest, and so on.

I've tried the following query, but it still returns null data for some years

```
WITH RECURSIVE ClosestStations AS (
SELECT 
    c.co_comarca,
    d.year,
    d.month,
    e.indicativo,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.co_comarca, d.year, d.month 
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_Transform(c.geom, 25830), ST_Transform(e.geom, 25830))) AS rn
FROM 
    referencia.comarcas_agrarias_centroides AS c
CROSS JOIN 
    referencia.estaciones_r_pen AS e
JOIN 
    tesis.datos_meteo AS d ON TRUE
WHERE 
    d.indicativo = e.indicativo
    AND d.month IN (4, 5, 6) 
)
SELECT 
    cs.co_comarca,
    cs.year,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cs.month = 4 THEN d.tm_mes END) AS tm_abr,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cs.month = 5 THEN d.tm_mes END) AS tm_may,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cs.month = 6 THEN d.tm_mes END) AS tm_jun,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cs.month = 4 THEN d.p_mes END) AS p_abr,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cs.month = 5 THEN d.p_mes END) AS p_may,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cs.month = 6 THEN d.p_mes END) AS p_jun
FROM 
    ClosestStations AS cs
LEFT JOIN 
    tesis.datos_meteo AS d ON cs.indicativo = d.indicativo AND cs.year = d.year AND cs.month = d.month
WHERE 
    cs.rn = 1 
    AND d.tm_mes IS NOT NULL
    AND d.p_mes IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    cs.co_comarca, cs.year;
```

**Edit**
You can download a subset of all three tables through [this link](https://disk.yandex.com/d/lgOW1PY-EdyGdA). Table names correspondences are:

- referencia.comarcas_agrarias_centroides = foo1
- referencia.estaciones_r_pen = foo2
- tesis.datos_meteo = foo3

I hope that column names and references are clear enough. Otherwise, just ask, please.

Comment: postgres recursion is funky, if your data isnt to big post it ill take a crack at it

Comment: I'm editing the post to add a subset of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have finally managed to get what I need, but using a workaround, not in one go.

First, I created two different views (one for temperature and the other for precipitation) with geom (of the meteo station), month and year with no null values:

```
create view temp_datos as
SELECT 
    d.year,
    d.month,
    e.geom,
    d.tm_mes
FROM 
    referencia.estaciones_r_pen AS e
JOIN 
    tesis.datos_meteo AS d 
on 
    d.indicativo = e.indicativo
    AND d.month IN (4, 5, 6) and d.tm_mes is not null;

create view precip_datos as
SELECT 
    d.year,
    d.month,
    e.geom,
    d.p_mes
FROM 
    referencia.estaciones_r_pen AS e
JOIN 
    tesis.datos_meteo AS d 
on 
    d.indicativo = e.indicativo
    AND d.month IN (4, 5, 6) and d.p_mes is not null;
```

Afterwards, I created a spatial query consisting in a join of two subqueries that return both the closest temp and precip data:

```
SELECT
consulta_temp.co_comarca,
consulta_temp.year,
consulta_temp.month,
consulta_temp.tm_mes,
consulta_precipit.p_mes
FROM (
-- Subquery for consulta_temp
SELECT
    c.co_comarca,
    d.year,
    d.month,
    d.tm_mes,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.co_comarca, d.year, d.month ORDER BY ST_TRANSFORM(c.geom, 25830) <-> ST_TRANSFORM(d.geom, 25830)) AS rn
FROM referencia.comarcas_agrarias_centroides AS c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        year,
        month,
        tm_mes,
        geom
    FROM temp_datos d
    ORDER BY 
        ST_TRANSFORM(c.geom, 25830) <-> ST_TRANSFORM(d.geom, 25830)
) AS d
) AS consulta_temp
JOIN (
-- Subquery for consulta_precipit
SELECT
    c.co_comarca,
    d.year,
    d.month,
    d.p_mes,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.co_comarca, d.year, d.month ORDER BY ST_TRANSFORM(c.geom, 25830) <-> ST_TRANSFORM(d.geom, 25830)) AS rn
FROM referencia.comarcas_agrarias_centroides AS c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        year,
        month,
        p_mes,
        geom
    FROM precip_datos d
    ORDER BY 
        ST_TRANSFORM(c.geom, 25830) <-> ST_TRANSFORM(d.geom, 25830)
) AS d
) AS consulta_precipit
ON consulta_temp.co_comarca = consulta_precipit.co_comarca
AND consulta_temp.year = consulta_precipit.year
AND consulta_temp.month = consulta_precipit.month
AND consulta_temp.rn = 1
AND consulta_precipit.rn = 1;
```